# Объяснить что и почему

Tags: c

Задача была - написать программу на чистом Си, которая будет выводить буквы в алфавитном порядке в одну линию. Нашёл что-то такое, и не могу понять, как и почему это (не) работает

```
int ft_putchar(char c);
void ft_print_alphabet(void) {
    int i = 'a';

    while (i <= 'z') {
        ft_putchar(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Задание было написать, а не найти.

Comment: Да вроде должно работать, но в пределах прописных английских букв.

Comment: @CrazyElf в коде используются строчные буквы.

Comment: Да, всё время их путаю ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем такие трудности?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
        printf("%c", ch);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

И вообще, зачем идти учиться, если всё равно не учиться?

Comment: 1. Без функции main не будет работать программа на С. 2.Создаём цикл, в котором объявляем переменную ch типа char и присваиваем ей начальное значение 'a', каждую итерацию производим вывод буквы на экран `printf("%c", ch)` (%c даёт знать printf, что единственный аргумент - символ) и увеличиваем значение ch (так как тип char, то каждую следующую итерацию значение будет равно 'b', 'c', 'd' и т.д.) до тех пор, пока значение переменной ch не будет равно 'z'. (Переменная char существует только во время цикла) 3.Выводим символ перевода строки.

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы предоставили не совсем точное условие задачи, я не могу Вам гарантировать, что такая реализация устроит Вашего преподавателя, но если отталкиваться от того, что Вы предоставили, то код программы будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
int main()
{
   int bukva;
    for(bukva = 65; bukva <= 90; bukva++)
    {
        printf("%c", bukva);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Объяснение кода:**

1) функция main - главная функция в любой программе (Т.к в с помощью нее происходит вход в программу и начинается ее выполнение)

2) Объявление переменной типа **int** с именем **bukva**

3) Создание цикла for и границ итераций (число 65 - не случайное, следует обратиться к ASCII таблице и всё станет ясно - [ASCII таблица](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii))

4) Вывод каждого значения переменной bukva/ используется стандартная функция вывода информации, а с помощью команды форматирования **%c** - выводится не числовое значение, а символ типа char соответствующий данному числовому значению по ASCII таблице.)

P.S Для вывода маленьких букв следует заменить числа **65** и **90** на **97** и **122** соответственно.

Comment: Вот уж что-что, а за транслит никакой преподаватель по головеке не погладит

Comment: @Don2Quixote я это прекрасно понимаю, но я специально так сделал, для более легкого понимания что это